# uint array and for loops in OpenCL

Tags: macos, opencl, gpgpu

I'm having a hard time in trying to figure out what is the problem in the following kernel:

```
__kernel void test(global unsigned char *word, int len) {

    uint chunks[16];

    // Init the array with zeros

    for (int i = 0;i<16; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",i);
        chunks[i] = 0;
    }

    // padding

    for (uint i = 0;i<len;i+=4) {

        chunks[i/4] = 0;
        for(uint j = 0;j<4 && i+j < len;j++) {

            uint c = word[i+j]<<(8*(3-j));
            chunks[i/4] |= c;

        }

    }

    // bit-wise print of the first element of the array, just as a test

     for (int j = 0;j<32;j++) {
        printf("%d ",(chunks[0]>>(31-j))&1);
    }
}
```

the kernel is meant to do a simple padding, storing 4 `char`s in a `uint`. For the moment this is just a test, so I'm just creating a single workgroup and the kernel will be actually executed just once.

The problem is that the program receives `SIGABRT` (didn't really understand when). 
Trying to track down the problem I noticed that the code seems to work properly if I comment out the "init" part, leaving the padding and the bit-wise print, and, conversely it works if I comment the padding, leaving the init and the print.
Moreover, I keep getting a `SIGABRT` if I remove the padding and replace the bit-wise print of the first element of `chunks` with a bit-wise print of the whole array

```
for (int i = 0;i<16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0;j<32;j++) {
        printf("%d ",(chunks[i]>>(31-j))&1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The code works fine if I launch it using the CPU instead of the GPU (using directly `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU` in the host code below).

I fear there is something conceptually wrong in what I'm doing, but didn't find any useful tip in the [specs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/specs/opencl-1.x-latest.pdf) or searching around the web.

I'm using MacOS 10.8.5. Here's my host code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char name[128];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL);

    if (queue == NULL) {
        queue = gcl_create_dispatch_queue(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, NULL);
    }

    // print name of the device 
    cl_device_id gpu = gcl_get_device_id_with_dispatch_queue(queue);
    clGetDeviceInfo(gpu, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, name, NULL);
    printf("Created a dispatch queue using the %s\n", name);


    unsigned char *word = (unsigned char*) malloc(7*sizeof(unsigned char));
    sprintf(word, "string");

    void* word_mem  = gcl_malloc(7 * sizeof(char), word,
                           CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR);

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{

        cl_ndrange range = {                                             
            1,
            {0, 0, 0},
            {1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0}
        };

        test_kernel(&range,(unsigned char*)word_mem, 6);

    });

    gcl_free(word_mem);    
    free(word);

    dispatch_release(queue);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can use 'printf' in your OpenCL kernel for the Nvidia GPU?

I suspect that printf only works for CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU or CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU + AMD.

Best regards,
Moisés

Comment: Well, my GPU is indeed an AMD (AMD Radeon HD 6750M). Moreover, if I could not use `printf` I would expect an error also in the cases in which, as I said, the program seems to work.

Comment: Ups, sorry. I've just tried your kernel in an AMD FirePro S9150 and it works perfectly using a host side code written in OpenCL C++. I don't know GCL of MacOS. Could you try to change your GCL code to an OpenCL code to discard that the problem is in the host side?

Comment: I'll give a try later.. It would sound weird if that's the case, as my host code closely mimic the "OpenCL hello world" apple provides in their docs. I'll let you know!

Comment: No luck yet. I followed a simple tutorial (http://www.fixstars.com/en/opencl/book/OpenCLProgrammingBook/calling-the-kernel/) but I keep getting a `SIGABRT`. Don't actually know when, since Xcode looks unable to debug a kernel and each part of the kernel seems to work when the others are commented out.